# How to avoid ExecStop status in systemctl status

Tags: service, systemctl, rhel8

systemctl status  command shows the ExecStop Failure message. Even though my service is up and running.

```
testDB.service - the testDB service
  Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/testDB.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
  Active: active (running) since Wed 2022-04-27 15:55:38 IST; 7s ago
 Process: 946 ExecStop=db/testDB/scripts/testDB.init stop (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Process: 995 ExecStart=db/testDB/scripts/testDB.init start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
```

Is there any way to avoid the ExecStop FAILURE message?

Answer (score -1):

Remove a line which begins from `ExecStop` from the systemd unit file for your service. Or make sure the script `testDB.init stop` always returns exit code 0

Comment: It's not a good idea to remove the proper way to stop a service from the systemd unit.

Comment: well .. I gave TS an alternative option to fix his init script. They are probably not looking for a proper way to stop a service.

Comment: Thank you for the comments both of you. I am checking my script.